# Flask JSON decode error: simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I am currently developing a webserver and when testing the output JSON this error is thrown:

```
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is the code for the webserver:

```
    from flask import Flask, request
    import json
    app = Flask(__name__)

    tasks=[]
    #Create a new task
    @app.route('/v1/tasks', methods=['POST'])
    def post():
        data=request.get_json()
        title=data["title"]
        tasks.append(json.dumps({"id": len(tasks)+1, "title": title, "is_completed": "false"}))
        #tasks[len(tasks)+1]={"title": title, "is_completed": "false"}
        index=len(tasks)
        return json.dumps({"id": index}), 201
```

This is the test I use:

```
    import requests
    import json

    response = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks', json={'title': "Test Task 2"})
    print(response.json())
    print(response.status_code)
```

That is the full error traceback:

```
  {'id': 5}
    201
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "project1-test2.py", line 42, in <module>
        print(response.json())
      File "/home/alexanderfarr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
        return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
        return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
    simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit: When just testing my get-function, I noticed that this is not even reached:

```
#List all tasks created
@app.route('/v1/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def getall():
   return json.dumps({"tasks": tasks})

#Get a specific task
@app.route('/v1/tasks/{id}', methods=['GET'])
def getone(id):
    print("in get")
    if id in tasks:
        print(tasks[id])
        return json.dumps(tasks[id]), 200
    else:
        return json.dumps({error: "There is no task at that id"}), 404
```

My code for testing:

```
import requests
import json
response=requests.get('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks/{1}')
print(response.json())
print(response.status_code)
```

In the console log, the print statements are not even shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1-test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "/home/alexanderfarr/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Is the JSON being received properly, everything is fine on that end?

Comment: {'id': 5} is received which should be correct

Comment: But how can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

If a Flask route returns a string with also arranging for a mimetype of `application/json`, the receiving end may not think it's getting JSON. Assuming you're using a recent Flask, returning a dict from route gets a free `jsonify`, which sets the mimetype of the response to `application/json` automatically.

Try

```
return {"id": index}, 201
```

Comment: Ok thank you, could you look at my edit and help me explain why the print statements are not even reached?

Comment: The print statements in the routes? Try replacing them with `app.logger.info()`

Comment: @Python-Data-Science-Learner That's a different issue entirely, no?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith, yes the print statements in the routes. Now, I see following: {"tasks": ["{\"is_completed\": \"false\", \"id\": 1, \"title\": \"Test Task 2\"}", "{\"is_completed\": \"false\", \"id\": 2, \"title\": \"Test Task 2\"}"]}    Why is there \" everywhere and how can I avoid that?

Comment: You're getting a double-encoding due to appending `json.dumps()` to `tasks`. Append the raw dict instead.